# How to scroll my dynamically generated HTML Page all the way down and start scrolling again from the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a HTML page that is just simple html page with an empty table tag.

This table is filled using a javascript function. I basically read a file and fill rows from the data of the file. This part I have implemented properly.

I have 100 table rows. I would like to scroll my HTML Page all the way down and then once it has finished scrolling starting to reverse the scroll back to top again.

I have found an example online: https://jsfiddle.net/maherhossain/a24nymv1/.
However, this only works horizontally. I have tried to do this vertically and have submitted the code below.

I am not getting any errors. The table is being loaded. Its just that the automatic scrolling is not working.

I would appreciate any help. Many Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll">
    <body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
<table class="content-table" id="demo"></table>
/div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll { white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
// {} ...Function to load the file in table

function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var scrollHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).clientHeight;
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollTop: scrollHeight - clientHeight },
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            targetElement.animate({ scrollTop: 0 },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#scroll'), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

scrollDown isn't an animation. Try scrollTop. You may have to rethink the math behind it though.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that,  it is doing the same thing.

Comment: function animatethis(targetElement, speed){
    var scrollHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight = $(targetElement).get(0).clientHeight;
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollTop: scrollHeight - clientHeight },
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            targetElement.animate({ scrollTop: 0 },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#scroll'), 6000);